# Socket.IO + Express: Obtaining the socket associated with an express session

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I am looking to raise application wide events from express http route handlers.
e.g a user modifies a record and an event is emitted to any other interested users.

In some cases I want to broadcast to all clients except the client making the (http) request.
This is possible by broadcasting against the socket you wish to exclude, however I do not currently have access to the socket associated with the session authenticating a http request.

I have seen [examples](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) which demonstrate how to retrieve the express session for a user from a socket request (i.e obtain session ID from cookie, retrieve session from sessionStore).

Is it possible to work in the inverse and perhaps store the socketId against the session for later retrieval? Can anyone identify any immediate caveats or gotchas with this approach?

Also are there implications if sockets are distributed across servers via a redis store?
I can foresee a scenario in which per user, http requests are coming in to a different node to socket requests.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would like to know this too, thanks for asking!

Comment: So you want to create a socekt with a custom `socketID`, right? I am not sure it's possible.

Comment: @Pio no. I want to save a `socketID` to a session, then later on retrieve the socket via that `socketID`.

Comment: Then just add it as a session variable/create a hashmap on the server side. But note that whenever the socket connection is interrupted/re-established between the client and the server the `socketID` is re-generated. I had a similar situation, so I kept a `sessionID:socketID` map and on `connect` (on the server side) I updated my map/on disconnect you can remove the `sessionID` or just set the `socektID` to `null`.

Comment: @Pio the drawbacks come when you consider scaling out to across multiple nodes. You need to share that hashmap across all the instances, which is possible via e.g Redis. 
But I'm not sure that it's possible to from one node, to obtain a socket that is connected to another node in order to broadcast from it (broadcast only in the sense that this is actually the one excluded socket)?

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Then I guess you need to try it out.